# Fetching data from 2 different AWS Neptune clusters with different IAM authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gremlin, amazon-neptune, neptune

I have a requirement where I want to fetch the data from 2 different AWS neptune endpoints, which are configured with different IAM roles/users. I will be having different access key and secret key for both the users.
As per document "https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/iam-auth-connecting-gremlin-java.html", we need to set access key and secret key as system properties.

So is the below way is correct to fetch data from 2 clusters.

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain;
import com.amazonaws.neptune.auth.NeptuneNettyHttpSigV4Signer;
import com.amazonaws.neptune.auth.NeptuneSigV4SignerException;

 ...

System.setProperty("aws.accessKeyId","your-access-key1");
System.setProperty("aws.secretKey","your-secret-key1");

 ...

Cluster1 = Cluster.build((your cluster name1))
                 .enableSsl(true)
                 .handshakeInterceptor( r ->
                  {
                    try {
                      NeptuneNettyHttpSigV4Signer sigV4Signer =
                        new NeptuneNettyHttpSigV4Signer("(your region)", new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain());
                      sigV4Signer.signRequest(r);
                    } catch (NeptuneSigV4SignerException e) {
                      throw new RuntimeException("Exception occurred while signing the request", e);
                    }
                    return r;
                  }
       
          ).create();
          
          
     ...

System.setProperty("aws.accessKeyId","your-access-key2");
System.setProperty("aws.secretKey","your-secret-key2");

 ...

Cluster2 = Cluster.build((your cluster name2))
                 .enableSsl(true)
                 .handshakeInterceptor( r ->
                  {
                    try {
                      NeptuneNettyHttpSigV4Signer sigV4Signer =
                        new NeptuneNettyHttpSigV4Signer("(your region)", new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain());
                      sigV4Signer.signRequest(r);
                    } catch (NeptuneSigV4SignerException e) {
                      throw new RuntimeException("Exception occurred while signing the request", e);
                    }
                    return r;
                  }
       
          ).create();
              
          
          
try {
  Client client2 = Cluster2.connect();
  client2.submit("g.V().has('code','IAD')").all().get();
} catch (Exception e) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Exception occurred while connecting to cluster", e);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NeptuneNettyHttpSigV4Signer` has a constructor like:

```
public NeptuneNettyHttpSigV4Signer(
        final String regionName, 
        final AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider)
```

The example in the Neptune documentation shows the most common and easy `AWSCredentialsProvider` to use (`DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain`) which among other things will check those system properties for credentials. In your case you have two different signings to do so using a system property probably isn't the best approach as multi-threaded environments will run into issues when reading and writing them.

It would be better if you supplied a different `AWSCredentialsProvider` for this case, one that specifically provided credentials for each cluster. You can see all the options available to you in the [javadocs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentialsProvider.html). Perhaps the most analogous approach to the code you're using would be to do:

```
NeptuneNettyHttpSigV4Signer sigV4Signer = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
"(your region)", 
new BasicAWSCredentials("<access-key>","<secret-key>"));
```

Of course, we're hardcoding credentials here so you might want to try an implementation that suits your case. The `AWSCredentialsProvider` is easy enough to implement yourself for custom solutions as well.